# Google Cloud PHP development environment

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, development-environment

We are wanting to develop a simple PHP application with the Google Cloud Environment and want advice on the best PHP development environment and approach.

We have setup the VM and have a PHP application. We can deploy the PHP application from Cloud Shell. Is there a quick application preview that can be run within the Cloud Shell and before we lengthy deploy process?  Or is there a better way that we have missed?

Comment: *"advice on the best [..]"* – That is too vague and broad to answer here. Please concentrate on things we *can* answer here. What kind of "quick preview" are you thinking about?

Comment: 1: Specifically wanting advice on what other developers use when developing PHP apps.

Comment: That is rather off-topic here as it has no concrete answer. Please ask concrete questions.

Comment: 2: When you make a simple change to your code, you want to a quick way to run the app and see the change. This is the "quick preview" option I referred to. The GCloud deploy process take many minutes and is too slow to support app development.

Comment: Do you develop PHP applications within the GCloud environment? And if so what tools and workflow do you use?

Comment: #2 is more answerable. I have no direct experience with Google Cloud in particular, but such kind of environments are hardly meant to be live coding environments. You're typically developing apps locally on your machine or a local server, and only deploy them to the cloud when you're already confident they work as they're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks deceze, good reply.  But I understand that you can't call online Google functions within your app when developing in a local environment. Is there an online PHP development environment where are can call online functions and also easily preview your application?

Comment: What "online functions" are you referring to, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SDK and App Engine SDK for PHP each include a local development server that you can run locally to simulate your application running in production App Engine. This server is the closest thing you can find, to your desired quick application preview. There is a [XDebug debugger](http://xdebug.org/) as well. You can check the "The PHP Development Server" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server) for details.

Comment: Thank you George, this is the best mature and informative answer. I was seeking guidance and you provided it.